# Dont understand Google Drive oAuth 2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, drive

I need oAuth2 on google drive . But i cant get  token. Which parameters is wrong ? Google documentation API cant help me for understanding what is wrong .
I do fetch request.

```
    const options = {
        method: 'post',
        client_id: '{EXAMPLE}deajshot.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        redirect_uri: 'https://drive.google.com/open?id={EXAMPLE}',
        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata',
        prompt: 'none',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        response_type: 'token'
    };
    fetch('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',options)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
```

Now i have error - 400. That’s an error.

Error: invalid_request

Required parameter is missing: response_type;

Answer (score 0):

By your code example , you first need to get a code and then request a access token.try to follow this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#authenticatingtheuser

You have there a request for example:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?
client_id=424911365001.apps.googleusercontent.com&
response_type=code&
scope=openid%20email&
redirect_uri=https://oauth2-login-demo.example.com/code&
state=security_token%3D138r5719ru3e1%26url%3Dhttps://oauth2-login-demo.example.com/myHome&
login_hint=jsmith@example.com&
openid.realm=example.com&
hd=example.com
```

After this , with your 'code' parameter you get you could make request to get a access token (you have there also a example of this request )

Good luck